# Android animation formats

Tags: animation, android

I would like to add some animation to an Android application, in which an icon would move from left to right along a horizontal line.

Our graphic designer suggested animated GIFs or MOV files, but we're not sure if these are the right formats for Android - especially in terms of file sizes.

Which animation file formats are supported by Android? Is there an official or recommended format by Google?

Comment: Hi, could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

A **PNG Sequence** is often used in my experience.

Example:

```
<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png -- wheel5.png files inside the
 res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this would be done in code using a custom animation. See Android's developer site for more info: [Defining Custom Animations](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#ViewState). Here, for example, is the code to morph from one shape to another, from [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <objectAnimator
     android:duration="3000"
     android:propertyName="pathData"
     android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0   -70,70z"
     android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
     android:valueType="pathType"/>
```

Comment: Hey KJP. Could you please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer itself so that it will remain useless if the link goes down or changes?